# String format, Javascript/Razor

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a formated string object tín the View of my MVC application. This string formats a Date of type wstring to format "yyyy-mm-dd". As such this string represent a date.

My problem is im trying to add two more string objects, one for year "yyyy" and one for month "MM". The reason for this is i have 3 checkboxes in my ViewModel which represent date, month and year like so:

```
    <td class="data" colspan="2">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Day)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Day)
    </td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="data" colspan="2">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Month)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Month) 
    </td>
</tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="data" colspan="2">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Year)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Year)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Depending on what checkbox have been cheked the corresponding JavascriptString should return the correct format.

This is my current script:

```
function (data) {
                var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                tdata.addColumn('date', 'Date');
                tdata.addColumn('number', 'Visitors');

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var dateStr = data[i].Date.substr(0, 4) + "-" + data[i].Date.substr(4, 2) + "-" + data[i].Date.substr(6, 2);
                    tdata.addRow([new Date(dateStr), parseInt(data[i].Visitors)]);
                }
```

My best guess is that month would be: `data[i].Date.substr(0, 4)`

And year would be: `data[i].Date.substr(4, 2)`

Allthough i need some kind of if statement that can determ what string to return.

Sorry i'm a beginner at Javascript.

Thx

Comment: Just use `DateTime.ToString("yyyy")`, `DateTime.ToString("MM")` and `DateTime.ToString("dd")` in your code behind instead of using javascript? And remember, `mm` for minutes, you need to use `MM` or `M` for months.

Comment: Right MM for month, thx. Well i did what you suggested in code behind first but Date it ended up in format "yyyyMMdd" which didn't look so good when the data was presented with Google Charts. I'm spitting the string as i prefer the separation with "-". The code behind is quite complexed and im kinda restricted as im working against a Google API, i thought this might be a alternative solution. Thx

Comment: use ToShorDateString() which will give you a better output